# Arduino save http variable

Tags: c++, http, variables, arduino

I want to compare on an Arduino when I get a HTTP message. I can see all requests. **How can I save the 'hello' displayed at the end and run code like: if 'hello', then do something.**

```
char buffer;
while (client.connected()) {
while (client.available()) {
buffer = client.read();
Serial.print(buffer);
}}
Serial.println("Closing connection");
Serial.println("");
client.close();
```

Serial Monitor:

```
Connect to 192.168.2.101:80
Connected & Data sent
TTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 30 Mar 2014 20:27:43 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.25 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.25 OpenSSL/0.9.8y
X-Powered-By: ZendServer 6.3.0
Set-Cookie: ZDEDebuggerPresent=php,phtml,php3; path=/
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

helloClosing connection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to parse the HTTP request.
Because limited RAM, keeping all request in memory is not a good idea, but look at the request: you have a list of header separated by `\n\r`, then an empty line (`\n\r`), then what you need.

So you have to look for `\n\r\n\r` and then save result. Something similat to:

```
char what[] = "\r\n\r\n";
String ris = "";
int eq = 0;
while (client.connected()) {
    while (client.available()) { //we assume all data to be in a single TCP packet.
        buffer = client.read();
        if (eq == 4){
            ris += buffer;
        }else{
            if (buffer == what[eq]){
                eq++;
            }else{
                eq = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    Serial.print("readed: ");
    Serial.println(ris);
    //here send answer
    client.close();
}
```

Comment: I try with your code, but nothing is displayed in serial monitor.. like this: Connected & Data sent
readed:

Comment: maybe... uhmm, try to remove \r (and so reduce the if of EQ to 2.. or change it to strlen(what), so you can change what[] without any more concern :)

Comment: I really don't know what you mean, i remove \r, change to eq 2, nothing work... i found this: if(result.endsWith("hello")){
        Serial.print("hello from php"); and it's working...

Comment: It is working unless you need a bit more ram.. can you link the modded code?

Comment: I make also a ram test, and each request i have always the same ram: 8763, but i'm interested in your solution, maybe more powerfull, feel free to edit. http://pastebin.com/4bS5uzAX,

Comment: 8000byte of ram? What kind of arduino are you usiNg? Btw you missed a \r in the string.. but it was right with them, just in the othee order, my bad! Edited the answer

Comment: Sorry,8000 is the wifi shield, my mistake. Now it's working, but i face one problem, when i read the second tag i lost the connection to the server...

Comment: i cant understand what you mean for tag.. maybe the HTML body? the please note that some server disconnect after sending data, but you still have it on the wifi's buffer, and you can read and get it with available.

Comment: I send a rfid tag to the server and server makes the tests to see if is available or not, so, when i scan the first tag everything is ok, the second says always connection failed, the third is again ok, this not happen with my old code... you can check: http://pastebin.com/RJMCHWvL

Comment: try with a bigger delay after connect() (best would be to loop until connected or timeout occur, with timeout of 1 or 2 seconds).. Also heck with wireshard or similar what appen to connection